# Server-side web browser for PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, browser, server-side

If you wanted to re-create the DOM server-side and manipulate it in PHP, how would *you* choose to go about it?

I'm looking for a fast, multi-user complete server-side web browser that can interface with PHP and run complete Javascript.

Like Jaxer but something I can use with PHP... an extension would be fine, or even an Apache mod.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd run Firefox on an instance of Xvfb and make sure the [MozRepl](http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl/) plugin was installed.

I'd then connect to the MozRepl server from PHP (using the [Perl module's](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MozRepl) source code to guide me in writing an API if I couldn't find a PHP one).

Answer (score 2):

> If you wanted to re-create the DOM server-side and manipulate it in PHP, how would you choose to go about it?

I'd use the [DOM extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

> I'm looking for a fast, multi-user complete server-side web browser that can interface with PHP and run complete Javascript.

Try any of these:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript

and have a look at

- http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?t=4603
- http://code.google.com/p/pampa-j/
- http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/03/php-to-jaxer-server-and-vice-versa.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any browser emulators for PHP that can execute javascript, but if you can do without that requirement, SimpleTest has a [browser component](http://www.simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/WebTester/SimpleBrowser.html) that's pretty nifty. It's part of the SimpleTest suite, but it can easily be used on its own.

Otherwise, your best bet is probably to remote-control Firefox or a Webkit-based browser. You can use [Xvfb](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html) (X virtual frame buffer) on Linux systems to run graphical programs under a scripting environment.

Answer (score 1):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is causing a bit of a stir at the moment. Could be worth looking into more.